# Find $x_1=a$ such that $x_{n+1}=x_n(x_n-1)$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

Given $x_1=a$, and $x_{n+1}=x_n(x_n-1). \forall n\in\mathbb{N*}$

Find the conditions of a such that $x_n$ converges.

**My attempts**

Now apparently if we assume $L$ is the limit with the correct $a$ then $L \in \{0,2\}$. I also guess that $a \in [0,2]$ because otherwise $|x_n-1| >1 \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$ which means $\lim x_n = +\infty$. I may try to prove harder that $a = L \in \{0,2\}$

So I first tried to quadrupled both sides, and got $4x_{n+1}+1=(2x_n-1)^2$.

Then I substitute $2x_n-1=y_n$ and got: $2y_{n+1}+3=y_n^2$

At this point I think I may have complicated things up

Any way to do otherwise? Please help!

Comment: I think $a \in [-1,2]$ might work. I think outside of that its easy to show divergence and if $f(x) = x^2 - x$ then $f([-1,2]) = [-0.25,2]$ and $f([-0.25, 2]) = [-0.25,2]$. So then for any $a \in [-1,2]$, we have that $x_n$ is bounded.

Hence, has a convergent subsequence. Now

$$f(f(x)) = f(x)^2 - f(x) = (x^2-x)^2 - x^2 + x = x^4 + x^2 - 2x^3 - x^2 + x = x(x^3 - 2x^2 + 1).$$

Now for $x \in [-0.25, 1]$ we have that $x^3 - 2x^2 + 1 \in [0,1]$. Thus, $x_{n+2} < x_{n}$ for $x_n \in [0,1]$. Hence these should converge to $0$ (it converges and must converge to a fixed point).

Comment: @RishiSonthalia Yeah I kinda forget that for $x_1 \in [-1,0]$ then $x_2 \in [0,2]$, thanks

Comment: You should write this in an answer. @RishiSonthalia

Comment: When given some recursion $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ I try to solve $L=f(L)$ to see if I can find naïve solutions.

Answer (score 1):

> $x_{n+1}=x_n(x_n-1)$ converges with $x_1=a$. Find the range of $a$.

Inspired by the comment.

\begin{align}
& \text{let }\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = C. \\
\Rightarrow \; & C=C^2-C, C^2=2C, C=0 \text{ or } C=2. \\
\ \\
& 2<x_n \Rightarrow 2<x_{n+1}. (x_{n+1}=x_n(x_n-1)>2\cdot1=2.) \\
\therefore \; & a\leq2. (\because \text{if } a>2: x_n>2, C>2.) \\
\ \\
& -1>x_n \Rightarrow 2<x_{n+1}. (x_{n+1}=x_n(x_n-1)=(x_n- \tiny \frac 1 2 \normalsize )^2-\tiny \frac 1 4 \normalsize>2.) \\
\therefore \; & a \geq -1. (\because \text{if } a<-1: x_n>2, C>2.) \\
\ \\
\Rightarrow \; & a \in [-1, 2]. \\
\ \\
& -1<x_n<2 \Rightarrow 0\leq x_{n+1}<2. (\because x_{n+1}=( x_n- \tiny \frac 1 2 
 \normalsize )^2-\tiny \frac 1 4 \normalsize \in [0, 2).) \\
\Rightarrow \; & \{x_n\} \text{ converges at } C=0. \tag{A}\label{A} \\
\ \\
& a=-1: x_2=2, C=2. \\
& a=2: x_2=2, C=2. \\ 
\ \\
\ \\
& \ref{A} : \text{oscillation doesn't happen, evidently.} \\
\end{align}